# Is there a way to change the position of the label position with <ui:inputText ...>?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I was wondering if there was a way to place the label on top of the field when using

```
<ui:inputText label="Expense Name" value="My Expense" required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the label class *uiLabel-top*.

```
<ui:inputText label="Expense Name" labelClass="uiLabel-top" value="My Expense" required="true"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Great, just what i needed thanks. Couldn't manage to find it myself.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Where can i find which other labelclasses are possible?

Comment: For this one, you have `uiLabel-top uiLabel-bottom uiLabel-left uiLabel-right`. Else you may use a custom class that you'll define yourself and add the css you want to the class.